# flutter app works with errors, possible internet connection issue

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am running into a possible internet connection issue, but I wanted to verify with the experts.

So whenever I reset the app, I see the following code (see code snip)

The app works fine, but why do I get the following errors::

**error 1: ( I see two of these logs)**

D/TrafficStats( 7324): tagSocket(120) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1

**error 2/3/4: (there are three logs of this!, I should only see one i think**

I/flutter ( 7324): user is already logged in yet

**error 5:**

W/DynamiteModule( 7324): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 arm64...
Restarted application in 846ms.
I/flutter ( 7324): User is not logged yet
D/EGL_emulation( 7324): app_time_stats: avg=27994.54ms min=27994.54ms max=27994.54ms count=1
I/flutter ( 7324): user is already logged in yet
W/DynamiteModule( 7324): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 7324): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 7324): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/flutter ( 7324): user is already logged in yet
D/TrafficStats( 7324): tagSocket(120) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
I/flutter ( 7324): user is already logged in yet
D/EGL_emulation( 7324): app_time_stats: avg=432.94ms min=27.87ms max=1386.56ms count=5
W/Firestore( 7324): (24.2.2) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
W/Firestore( 7324): 
W/Firestore( 7324): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
D/TrafficStats( 7324): tagSocket(120) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a network issue!

`D/TrafficStats( 7324): tagSocket(120)` [for read](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats) from Android dev docs.

On your log second last line its stated clearly.

`W/Firestore( 7324): This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.`

Other errors are from Firebase and Firestore libraries which are caused by the network issue.